# Allegro 5 loop through config file values with the same name

Tags: c++, configuration-files, allegro5

I have a config file that store a map

```
name=map1
width=5
height=5
[tiles]
   l=0,0,1,0,0
   l=0,1,1,1,0
   l=0,1,0,1,0
   l=0,1,0,1,0
   l=0,0,0,0,0
[/tiles]
```

How can i loop through the [tiles] section to store his lines(l) values into my vector?

**Note: i put the allegro5 tag cause it have functions for load configuration files.**

Comment: I guess you would need to determine when to stop reading.  Looks like the phrase `[/tiles]` is the end of the loop.  So when you read a line and it contains the text, `break` out of the loop.

Comment: What does your question have to do with `allegro5` tag, when it is about parsing a configuration file?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews i put the allegro5 tag cause i am making a game in that library and allegro5 includes functions for load configuration files, so i do not need to write my own code or import external libraryes to parse configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, Allegro will only take the last of a number of entries
with the same key. While you could give each row a different key, you could
instead take advantage of the fact that the `=` assignment is optional:

```
[tiles]
   0,0,1,0,0
   0,1,1,1,0
   0,1,0,1,0
   0,1,0,1,0
   0,0,0,0,0
[/tiles]
```

Now the data for each row is stored in the 'key' itself, and the 'value' is
ignored.

```
int main() {
    ALLEGRO_CONFIG *cfg;
    ALLEGRO_CONFIG_ENTRY *entry;
    const char* row;

    al_init();

    cfg = al_load_config_file("config.cfg");

    row = al_get_first_config_entry(cfg, "tiles", &entry);
    while (entry) {
        printf("%s\n", row);
        row = al_get_next_config_entry(&entry);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tanks!, that is very more handy and usefull that my answer, it looks you know about allegro5, i tink the allegro5 tag does not seems be very active in Stack Overflow, Tank for your answer.

Comment: Indeed, its not that active like in the past. Back there at the [forum](http://www.allegro.cc) we have slightly more activity :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a to do this after a while of reading the allegro5 reference and witing and trying and trying again so there is a answer my own question:

first the entrys of the [tiles] section may have different names, like that:

```
[tiles]
   a=0,0,1,0,0
   b=0,1,1,1,0
   c=0,1,0,1,0
   d=0,1,0,1,0
   e=0,0,0,0,0
[/tiles]
```

then the code is:

```
ALLEGRO_CONFIG*config_file=al_load_config_file("example.map");
vector<const char*>lines
ALLEGRO_CONFIG_ENTRY** entry_iterator;
const char* entry;
entry=al_get_first_config_entry(config_file, "tiles", entry_iterator);
while((entry=al_get_next_config_entry(entry_iterator))!=NULL){
        lines.push_back(al_get_config_value(config_file, "tiles", entry));
};
```